# Proving a subclass of modules is closed under extensions using some categorical properties.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, modules, homological-algebra

Let $Mod(R)$ be the category of modules over some ring $R$. We say $p: Mod(R) \to Mod(R)$ is a **pre-radical** if $p$ is a sub-functor of the identity functor over $Mod(R)$. Also, we say that a pre-radical is  **radical** if $r(\frac{M}{r(M)})=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ for every module $M \in Mod(R)$. Lets consider a radical $r$  and the following subclass of $Mod(R)$

$$\tau_{R}:= \lbrace M \in Mod(R) \:  | \: r(M)=M \rbrace.$$

I want to prove this subclass is closed under extensions, that means that if I got an exact sequence

$$0 \to M' \to M \to M'' \to 0$$

where $M', M'' \in \tau_{R}$, then $M \in \tau_{R}$. I have read about this class and some books said this is a torsion class of a torsion theory this means this class is closed under extensions but nobody discuss the prove of this fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us assume for convenience of notation that $M'$ is actually a submodule of $M$ and $M''=M/M'$.  Note that $M'=r(M')\subseteq r(M)$, so there is a surjective homomorphism $p:M''=M/M'\to M/r(M)$.  Applying $r$ to this homomorphism, we get a commutative diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
r(M'') @>{}>> r(M/r(M))\\
@V{\cong}VV @V{0}VV \\
M'' @>{p}>> M/r(M)
\end{CD}$$
where the left vertical map is an isomorphism by hypothesis and the right vertical map is $0$ since $r(M/r(M))=0$.  This implies that $p=0$, but $p$ was surjective, so $M/r(M)=0$.  That is, $r(M)=M$, as desired.

Comment: Very accurate and well explained, never have solved these kind of problems. Thanks a lot! @EricWofsey